# C# Structs: Unassigned local variable?

Tags: c#, struct

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saxz13w4.aspx):

> Unlike classes, structs can be instantiated without using a new operator.

So why am I getting this error:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'x'

When I try to do this?

```
        Vec2 x;
        x.X = det * (a22 * b.X - a12 * b.Y);
        x.Y = det * (a11 * b.Y - a21 * b.X);
```

Where `Vec2 x` is a struct?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, are X and Y properties (rather than fields)? If so, that's the problem. Until all the fields within `x` are definitely assigned, you can't call any methods or properties.

For instance:

```
public struct Foo
{
    public int x;
    public int X { get { return x; } set { x = value; } }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo a;
        a.x = 10; // Valid

        Foo b;
        b.X = 10; // Invalid
    }
}
```

Is `Vec2` your own type? Do you have access to the fields involved, or only the properties?

If it's your own type, I would *strongly* urge you to try to stick to immutable structs. I know managed DirectX has some mutable structs for getting as close to optimal performance as possible, but that's at the cost of strange situations like this - and much worse, to be honest.

I would personally give the struct a constructor taking X and Y:

```
 Vec2 x = new Vec2(det * (a22 * b.X - a12 * b.Y),
                   det * (a11 * b.Y - a21 * b.X));
```

Comment: Ah, they were properties. Good catch! I'll consider making X and Y private if I can get away with it.

Comment: I am very new to this and would definitely appreciate an answer to this doubt: If I can set x directly as shown, what is the use of having a setter method? I have the same problem, however, the struct I have has x set as private public getter and setter methods to manipulate it. How should I work with that?

Comment: @darnir: The use is that you normally *wouldn't* make the field publicly available. Your situation isn't really clear, and is probably worth a separate question - I'd expect there to be a constructor taking all the relevant fields.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks for your reply. There was no constructor to the struct I was using. I made all the fields private and created a constructor for the struct. It now works fine.

Comment: It seems the compiler is also not happy if you set any of the fields in an if/else, even though it is definitely set as a result.

Comment: @xr280xr I'd expect that to work - can you reproduce in a gist?

Comment: @JonSkeet - I can't reproduce it! Maybe I had a typo on one of my fields before, or VS was being crazy. Sorry & thanks!

Answer (score 9):

It is still uninitialized. You need to initialize it before using it. You can use `default` operator for that if you don't want to create a static `Vec.Empty` value and happy with the defaults for the structs members:

```
Vec2 x = default(Vec2);
```

Mitch Wheat:

This, however doesn't:

```
public struct Vec2
{
    int x;
    int y;

   public float X { get { return x; } set { x = value; } }
   public float Y { get { return y; } set { y = value; } }

}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Vec2 x;

    x.X = 1;
    x.Y = 2; 
}
```

The compiler prevents you from calling propertis on types before all of it's members have been initialized, even though a property might just set one of the values. The solution, as Jon Skeet proposed, is to have an initializing constructor and preferably no setters.