# How do I fix Error CS0165: "Use of unassigned local variable 'a'"?

Tags: c#, forms

I want to create output from a CSV in Windows Forms

```
 public struct Artikel
    {
        public String id;
        public double d;
        public double dmin;
        public double I;
        public double d2;
        public double e;
        public double I1;
        public double I2;

    }
```

Now I am declaring the Path

```
 private void buttonEingabe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var tabelle = Tabelle.getTabel(@"C:\Users\alexa\source\repos\metallBohrrer\metallBohrrer\db.csv");
        int index = 0;
        int anzahl = tabelle.Length;
        string temp = textBoxpk.Text;
        int tempint = 0;

        for (; index < anzahl;)
        {
            if (temp == tabelle[index].id)
            {
                tempint = index;
            }

            index++;
        }

        textBoxpk.Text = tabelle[tempint].id;
        //   textBox2.Text = tabelle[tempint].d;
        //   textBox3.Text = tabelle[tempint].dmin;


    }
```

After that I want to declare it and here I see the errors "CS0165 C# Use of unassigned local variable 'a'" and "CS0136 C# A local or parameter named cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter."

```
public static class Tabelle
    {
        public static Artikel[] getTabel(String Datei)
        {
            List<Artikel> artikel = new List<Artikel>();
            String[] zeilen = File.ReadAllLines(Datei);
            foreach (String zeilen in zeilen)
            {
                String[] data = zeilen.Split(';');
                Artikel a;
                a.id = data[0];

                artikel.Add(a);

            }
            return artikel.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

I really don't know why it won't build.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? You need to assign your variable.

Comment: You should use `class`, not `struct`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not assigning anything to your variable that you declare on line 10 of your Tabelle class. You might want to make Artikel a class, and then try this:

```
Artikel a = new Artikel();
a.id = data[0];
```

EDIT: If you're determined to use a struct, this answer might help: [C# Structs: Unassigned local variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069435/c-sharp-structs-unassigned-local-variable)

Comment: Thank you for your help